# JS Function with fetch : Access once at a time

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I have the following JS function that fetches data and put in a `window.data` property:

```
function fetchData() {
  if (window.data) {
    return Promise.resolve(window.data)
  } else {
    return fetch('http://example.com/data.js')
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(json => window.data = json)
  }
}
```

The code works fine.
However, when there are two concurrent calls to that function, the first call to `fetchData` will fire the `fetch`.
Because the `fetch` can take some time, a second call to `fetchData` won't find anything in the `window.data` and fire the same `fetch`.

Question :
How can I send an elegant `pending` signal to the second call and return the result as a resolved promise ?
Unless a promise-based solution is not possible, is there any another approach I can dig ?

The ideal solution should not block the second block but instead deal with it asynchronously with promises

Regards

I tried a mutex-based solution but it seemed over complicated.

Comment: This is a very difficult design to program with because `fetchData()` sometimes returns the data and sometimes returns a promise.   Probably, you should just always return a promise that resolves to your data.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank for your suggestion. I edited the code snippet.
However, I can't understand how a promise can solve that problem ?
Regards

Comment: Change `return ….then(json => window.data = json);` to `return window.data = ….;` (and then rename `data` to `dataPromise`)